# Restoring touch functionality for a touchscreen laptop?

Tags: kde, touchscreen, multi-touch

I just installed Ubuntu with KDE on Latitude 5289, it's a Dell laptop that normally has some pretty nifty touchscreen functionality. For example, on Windows, this machine would be able to scroll up and down web pages and documents by dragging a finger over the screen, or zoom in and out using two fingers.

Right now in KDE Ubuntu 21.10, touching the screen just warps the mouse cursor to where I touch. I'm very new to Linux, is there anything like drivers I may be able to install that could restore some of the previous functionality? Or will I just have to do without on linux? Also let me know if there's any other system information I need to provide to clarify. Thank you very much for reading and any help.

Comment: I am using Plasma on Wayland using Kubuntu 23.10.  The touch screen was kind of working -- Now it has stopped.  I saw in the settings a strange option that touchscreen won;t work when the mouse of mouse pad is active -- That can't be right, can it!!?

Answer (score 1):

Everyone, I have found the solution. When I installed kubuntu, it started Plasma on X11. If you **switch your desktop environment to Plasma on Wayland**, you may well find your touchscreen functionality restored, as I have.